# Trailing margin after doing corner radius

Tags: ios, swift

I am new in iOS and creating an `UITableView` using swift. I have to margin on both leading and trailing. Everything works smooth so far. Problem starts when I do corner radius with the following code:

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: parentView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
let mask = CAShapeLayer()
mask.path = path.CGPath
parentView.layer.mask = mask
```

When I do corner radius not two margins (leading and trailing) working simultaneously. Whether the leading or the trailing works at a time but not both.
Please suggest me what should I do.

**Update 1:** I am doing the margin from `XIB`.

**Update 2:** Here is the screenshot of `IB`

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just set parentView.layer.cornerRadius?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your layout constraints in the IB? And what exactly is parentView?

Comment: @Tapani: because I am not doing radius on all corners.

Comment: Is parentView same as the contentView? Have you tried to set the mask to the actual cell not he contentView?

Comment: ParentView is the `Title` (`UILable`).

Comment: What is the radius you are using and what is the value of "corners"?

Comment: `.BottomLeft, .BottomRight`